# Select2 4.0 infinity scroll without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I have 10 000 options for select2 and it work very slow. In 3.4 version i can do infinity scroll like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7bDG/1/. But in 4.0 i don't have `options.page` param into query function and it don't run when scroll end.

How it do for select2 4.0 version?